# Creating a list in ListAdded List Event Receiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint, programmatically-created, event-receiver

I am trying to programmatically create a Calendar List in SharePoint 2010 whenever a particular list is created using a Sandbox Solution.  I have implemented a ListAdded ListEventReceiver in order to run the code to generate the calendar.

```
public class GenerateCalendar : SPListEventReceiver
{
   public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
   {
      base.ListAdded(properties);

      // Exit out if this is not a MyList type
      if(!IsMyList(properties))
         return;

      string calendarTitle = properties.List.Title + " Calendar";

      SPWeb spWeb = properties.Web;
      SPListTemplateType type = new SPListTemplateType();
      type = SPListTemplateType.Events;

      // Execution breaks here:
      Guid listGuid = spWeb.Lists.Add(calendarTitle, "Associated Calendar", type);
      SPList newList = spWeb.Lists[listGuid];
      newList.OnQuickLaunch = properties.List.OnQuickLaunch;
      newList.Update();
   }
}
```

When I call **spWeb.Lists.Add(...)**, I get an SPException (The sandboxed code execution requested was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request.)

From the MSDN documentation, I can see that that the SPListCollection.Add method *is* available in Sandboxed Solutions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms413986(v=office.14).aspx).  Is there a restriction against creating a list in this event receiver like this?  Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Edited to add the generated Feature.xml and Elements.xml files

Feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
   Title="Calendar Generator"
   Description="Generates a calendar"
   Id="dfe3388c-c063-4873-a41b-5c066907c510"
   Scope="Web">
   <ElementManifests>
      <ElementManifest Location="GenerateCalendar\Elements.xml" />
   </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Receivers >
      <Receiver>
         <Name>GenerateCalendarListAdding</Name>
         <Type>ListAdding</Type>
         <Assembly>MyListGenerator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5cff2198a602ec41</Assembly>
         <Class>MyListGenerator.Event_Receivers.GenerateCalendar.GenerateCalendar</Class>
         <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
         <Name>GenerateCalendarListDeleting</Name>
         <Assembly>MyListGenerator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5cff2198a602ec41</Assembly>
         <Class>MyListGenerator.Event_Receivers.GenerateCalendar.GenerateCalendar</Class>
         <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
         <Name>GenerateCalendarListAdded</Name>
         <Type>ListAdded</Type>
         <Assembly>MyListGenerator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5cff2198a602ec41</Assembly>
         <Class>MyListGenerator.Event_Receivers.GenerateCalendar.GenerateCalendar</Class>
         <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
   </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  Apparently creating a list within this event receiver was causing a recursive call to the event receiver, even though I had a check in place to exit out on non-*MyList* template-based lists.  The solution was to simply add `EventFiringEnabled = false`.

```
...
SPWeb spWeb = properties.Web;
SPListTemplateType type = new SPListTemplateType();
type = SPListTemplateType.Events;

EventFiringEnabled = false;  // Disable event firing and create the list
Guid listGuid = spWeb.Lists.Add(calendarTitle, "Associated Calendar", type);
SPList newList = spWeb.Lists[listGuid];
newList.OnQuickLaunch = properties.List.OnQuickLaunch;
newList.Update();
EventFiringEnabled = true;  // Re-enable event firing
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create event receivers that derive from `SPListEventReceiver` in a sandboxed solution. However, the event receiver must be registered [declaratively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430602(v=office.14).aspx) in your feature elements file; it cannot be registered using the object model (such as via a feature receiver).

Most likely you are running into a restriction on the amount of *resource points* your sandboxed solution is permitted to consume, although you may also be running into the absolute limit of resources that can be consumed per request.

Additionally, if your environment runs particularly slowly, the user code service will recycle if its time limit (30 seconds by default) is exceeded during a single request.

For more information, refer to the "**Understanding Solution Monitoring**" section of this **Sandboxed Solutions** documentation from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx

Relevant excerpts follow.

**Resource Points:**

> If the solutions in a site collection exceed the daily resource point allocation for that site collection, SharePoint will take every sandboxed solution in the site collection offline for the rest of the day.
>
> Resource points are calculated according to 14 different measurements known as resource measures, including CPU execution time, memory consumption, and unhandled exceptions.
>
> ...
>
> SharePoint counts the most expensive resource measure toward the total for the solution, instead of the sum of all measures.

**Absolute Limits:**

> To prevent rogue sandboxed solutions from causing instability SharePoint also monitors individual sandboxed solutions per request. Each of the 14 resource measures includes an **AbsoluteLimit** property that defines a hard limit of the resources that a sandboxed solution can consume in a single request. If an absolute limit is exceeded, SharePoint terminates the request by stopping and restarting the Sandbox worker process. For example, the CPU execution time resource measure has a default absolute limit of 60 seconds. If a single request takes more than 60 seconds to execute, the user code service will stop and restart the sandbox worker process that is executing the request.

**WorkerProcessExecutionTimeout:**

> In addition, the user code service includes a property named **WorkerProcessExecutionTimeout** with a default value of 30 seconds. If this time limit is exceeded during a single request, the user code service will recycle the application domain in question and the request will return an error.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be any of these things. The event receiver is registered declaratively. I let Visual Studio handle that, but I verified the Feature.xml and Elements.xml that are generated against the example in documentation you linked and it matches up fairly well (with the exception of lacking a ListTemplateId attribute in the Receivers tag of the Elements.xml).  I edited my question and added the output of the files to the end.

Comment: As far as the **WorkerProcessExecutionTimeout**, I tested it several times to see how long it takes before I receive the exception and it was consistently about 10 seconds.  I verified the value of **WorkerProcessExecutionTimeout** (set to 30) through PowerShell and even tried changing it to 60, but it didn't make a difference.  The exception occurs after only 10 seconds.  Resource usage is about 0.07 (although that number seems to fluxuate from 0 to 0.15).  Any other ideas as to what may be causing this?